# Center Logo Over Navigation Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to center the logo over the navigation and have it slightly cover banner image(image below). I'm not sure what the best modern approach do so would be to achieve this. I cant seem to get it to overlay over the nav and onto the banner. I'm using flexbox. I tried using z-index and matop to push it down over the two elements, but it doesn't seem to work. Is this the best approach to create the visual? Am I missing some CSS?  Any help is much appreciated thank you!

[image]
This is what Im getting with the code below
[image]

```
 <header class="header">
      <img class="logo" src="img/stPaulProperLogo.png">
    </header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Fixed navbar</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
              <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
                </li>
              </ul>

            </div>
          </nav>

<header id="banner"></header>
```

CSS

```
.header{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 25vh;
    background:black;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

}




.logo{
z-index: 6;
margin-top: 100px;
height: 138px;
width: 138px;
```

}

Comment: why did you add header height 25vh.. you should remove this its working fine

Comment: @Jedi mindTricker you should post jsfiddle or codepan to check the problem

Comment: don't use margin...move the element using `position:relative` and then move it down. That should work

Answer (score 1):

**RESULT**
[image]

**HTML**

```
<header class="header">
  <img class="logo">
</header>

<nav class="navbar">
  <ul><li>Home</li> <li>Menu</li> <li>About</li></ul>
</nav>

<header id="banner"></header>
```

**CSS**

```
.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 25vh;  
  background: black;
  display: flex;

  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.logo {
  background: yellow;
  width: 138px;
  height: 138px;

  margin-bottom: -100px;
}
```

**DEMO**

https://codepen.io/wilsonbalderrama/pen/GRgZwXW

Answer (score 0):

you can change html file to this:

```
<header class="header">
    <div class="logo">
       <img src="img/stPaulProperLogo.png" />
    </div>
</header>
```

and then remove *margin-top: 100px;* from your css flie and define width and height for img tag and help from position property! 
like this:

```
.logo {
    z-index: 6;
    height: 80%;
    width: 8%;
    position: relative;
}

.logo img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 60%;
}
```

Hopefully this code will give you the result you want.

Comment: Thank you for responding, but I'm trying to use flexbox properties. Thank you for your help tho.